# How to create a boot USB flash drive with DOS and GPT/UEFI?

Tags: windows, boot, usb, gpt, ms-dos

I need to run a DOS application from the flash drive on boot, so I can create a backup image of the main hard disk. I have been doing this procedure for many years so far, but my new laptop is compabible only with GPT/UEFI. Please, can I create a bootable usb flash drive with DOS and GPT/UEFI? If yes, how? If not, is there any workaround? Thank you!

Comment: Your question is confusing.  GPT is a partition layout.  UEFI the replacement to BIOS.  You cannot use the two interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any workaround?

In a modern computer (UEFI, GPT and Secure Boot), you cannot boot DOS directly.

Workaround?

**(A)** Try setting up Powershell to do the backup.  That may work and is probably the best chance to work.

[Run Powershell at startup](https://jd-bots.com/2021/05/15/how-to-run-powershell-script-on-windows-startup/https://)

> This is useful when you want to run any automation created using
> PowerShell on Windows Startup. To run PowerShell script on startup.
>
> Create a Windows Command Script (.cmd file) i.e. create a file and
> save it with .cmd extension.
>
> Write the below command in .cmd file.
>
> powerShell path\to\powershell_script.ps1 >> “path\to\log_file.log”
>
> If you want to run the script in background. Add -windowstyle hidden
> after powershell.
>
> Place the file or its shortcut file at below path.
>
> C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
> Menu\Programs\Startup
>
> Restart the computer and you can track its execution in log file.

===========

**(B)** You might also consider a modern App that can create an image of a modern system.  Acronis or like that will start with a USB Key.

This is probably the easiest of the 2 methods. With Windows 10 / 11 and Repair Install, there is less need to make images.

Comment: thank you for your answer!

Comment: Thanks and good luck with your requirements